# Intel HD graphics driver for 15.04

Tags: 15.04, intel-graphics, intel

I want to install the intel graphics HD driver on my Ubuntu 15.04 system. However, the installer from `01.org` only works up to 14.10 (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.1.0)

Is there any other (easy) way to install the driver? Any ppa...?

Answer (score 0):

Intel Graphics Installer now 1.2.0 supports Ubuntu 15.04.

1. Download [Intel Graphics Installer 1.2.0](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0)
2. Add Intel certificate :

   ```
   wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
   sudo apt-key add -

   wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
   sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Install it:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_*.deb
   ```
4. Run the installer.

---

Refer on the [Intel Graphics Installer page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0) for more information.

Comment: thanks, I saw this. However, the problem is still that they always support only one ubuntu version at a time...

Comment: Indeed... Moreover Ubuntu 15.10 is coming in a month. I hope they won't take that long for the new version...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest graphics drivers using the following repository, but it is **IMPORTANT** that you remove the `intel-linux-graphics-installer` before doing so.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
```

press yes to add it and then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Lastly, reboot your computer and you will have the latest stable graphics driver installed.

There is only one caveat with adding this repository, which might be that you need to remove it before upgrading Ubuntu to let's say Ubuntu 17.10 when that arrives.

You can remove the repository by writing this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

When the new Ubuntu has been installed, simply add the repository again to automatically get the newest updates again. BTW, this repository also works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

This repository will automatically update your graphics driver, whenever a new update is released.